# "a little boy" Vs. "a small boy"

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

Can I say that **"a little boy"** refers to the age whereas "**a small boy**" refers to the size? Or both can be interchangeable also in meaning?

For example:

> He is **a little** boy.

Also I would like to know about:

> He is **a little** friend.

Comment: Again, some examples are needed, as context is everything. But probably not age related specifically, other than the fact that boys grow larger as they age, so it is still about size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. A **little boy** means a **young boy**, and a **small** boy refers to his **size**.

See here ([Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/little)):

> **little** (adjective) young:
>
> When you were **little**, you and your brother were always fighting.
>
> My **little** brother/sister (= younger brother or sister) is seven years
>   old.
>
> He stayed home from work today because his **little** boy/girl (=young son
>   or daughter) is sick.

Answer (score 1):

> A little boy

Refers to a young boy by age, has nothing to do with the actual size of the boy while

> A small boy

Refers to the size of the boy and has nothing to do with the age of the child

Answer (score -2):

No, it's not like the way you understand. Both talk about the *size* **in this context.**

However, I ***guess*** 'small' is more common in BrE (the smallest watch) whereas 'little' is what you find more in AmE (the littlest watch). But as I said, this is just a guess.

Another thing is *little* some times depict *emotions* as in *'a poor little girl'*

I checked COCA where 'little boy' outnumbers 'small boy' in usage.

Out of the context of a *boy,* they aren't interchangeable always. You may have *little experience* in driving a car, but you cannot have *small!*

Comment: *A little boy* normally means a young boy. *A small boy* always means a boy who is small in size.

Comment: @Maulik, unfortunately your answer isn't correct. I found now that Cambridge says literally that **little** has a meaning of **young**. See here: dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/little